# no eigenvalues from scipy...eigs ArpackNoConvergence error?

Tags: scipy

I'm using scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.

In the docs, it says "The currently converged eigenvalues and eigenvectors can be found as eigenvalues and eigenvectors attributes of the exception object.", but when I look at these attributes, they are empty arrays.

What does this mean?  Why isn't there anything there?

docs:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html

Answer (score 0):

These attributes contain only the converged eigenvalues.
If no eigenvalues have been found to accuracy specified by the tolerance, these results are empty.

Comment: OK, I was confused because I am only looking for the largest eigenvalue, but I guess if I was looking for more, it could find the first n, and then fail to converge when looking for the n+1st, and you could still get the first n out as attributes of the exception.